# JVM Parameters Not Being Applied Despite Being Set in Kubernetes ConfigMap

Tags: java, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, amazon-eks, apache-pulsar

I have a Pulsar cluster running an EKS (kubernetes) cluster. I've been advised to try and increase the JVM heap size on of the pods (called toolset) as advised by one of our support vendors:

> You are running this directly from the toolset pod, and the toolset pod's JVM heap allocation is very small compared to the RAM
> allocated to the pod. Because the Pulsar Producers need to use a
> buffer to batch messages, if the JVM heap is small, it will be less
> efficient at sending messages at high traffic. We recommend increasing
> the JVM heap size using the new JVM ops to control their size by
> percentages:
> https://www.baeldung.com/java-jvm-parameters-rampercentage. Once set,
> please restart the pod.

Following the baeldung site above I'm trying to set the parameters:

- `XX:InitialRAMPercentage=50.0`
- `XX:MinRAMPercentage=80.0`
- `XX:MaxRAMPercentage=60.0`

I set these variables in my `values.yaml` and I can see after applying these changes that they are reflected in the configmap:

```bash
➜ kubectl -n pulsar describe configmap event-platform-pulsar-0-sn-toolset 
...
Data
====
PULSAR_MEM:
----
-XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=128M -XX:InitialRAMPercentage=50.0 -XX:MinRAMPercentage=80.0 -XX:MaxRAMPercentage=60.0
httpServerPort:
----
8000
log4j2.yaml:
----
...
```

However, when I try and check the value of `MaxRAMPercentage` on the toolset pod, I see the original value.

```
➜ kubectl exec -it event-platform-pulsar-0-sn-toolset-0 -n pulsar -- java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version | grep -E "MaxRAMPercentage"

   double MaxRAMPercentage                         = 25.000000                                 {product} {default}
```

Despite the JVM memory parameters being correctly set in the ConfigMap and appearing in the Kubernetes manifest, they do not seem to be applied to the running JVM, as indicated by the `MaxRAMPercentage` still being set to the default value. What could be causing this issue, and how can I correctly set these parameters?

### Further Troubleshooting Results

I added the environment variable `-XX:+PrintFlagsFinal`

```
    PULSAR_MEM: >
      -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=128M
      -XX:InitialRAMPercentage=50.0
      -XX:MinRAMPercentage=80.0
      -XX:MaxRAMPercentage=60.0
      -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal
```

This the startup logs:

```
➜ kubectl logs event-platform-pulsar-0-sn-toolset-0 -n pulsar
[conf/client.conf] Applying config authParams = {"privateKey":"file:///pulsar/oauth2_keys/OAUTH2BROKERCREDS","issuerUrl":"https://api.climate.com/api/oauth","audience":"platform.climate.com","scope":""}
[conf/client.conf] Applying config authPlugin = org.apache.pulsar.client.impl.auth.oauth2.AuthenticationOAuth2
[conf/client.conf] Applying config brokerServiceUrl = pulsar://event-platform-pulsar-0-sn-broker:6650/
[conf/client.conf] Applying config webServiceUrl = http://event-platform-pulsar-0-sn-broker:8080/
[conf/bookkeeper.conf] Applying config httpServerEnabled = true
[conf/bookkeeper.conf] Applying config httpServerPort = 8000
[conf/bookkeeper.conf] Applying config statsProviderClass = org.apache.bookkeeper.stats.prometheus.PrometheusMetricsProvider
[conf/bookkeeper.conf] Applying config useHostNameAsBookieID = true
[conf/bookkeeper.conf] Applying config zkLedgersRootPath = /ledgers
[conf/bookkeeper.conf] Applying config zkServers = event-platform-pulsar-0-sn-zookeeper:2181
Configuring pulsarctl context ...
Successfully configured pulsarctl context.
```

Comment: It seems unlikely to me that a standalone `java -version` invocation would honor a `PULSAR_MEM` environment variable.  Can you add the `-XX:+PrintFlagsFinal` into the `PULSAR_MEM` setting instead; then its output should be in `kubectl logs`?

Comment: @DavidMaze Thanks for the suggestion, I did try and the logs didn't show the PULSAR_MEM variables. I've posted the output in my question above.